# Separating Id from string by using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

how can I get the first part of ID from the following string?

```
sText ='DefId #AnyId #MyId';
sText = sText.replace(/ #.*$/g, '');
alert(sText);
```

The result should be as follows: "DefId #AnyId "

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I use js and jQuery.

Comment: Are you asking about Python or JavaScript? Tags should relate to the question.

Comment: JavaScript, I am trying to separate an Id-Name from string in jQuery.

Comment: replace will dump the value found in the regexp

Comment: Thank you, It works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sText ='DefId #AnyId #MyId';
var matches = sText.match(/(DefId #.*) #.*/);
if(matches && matches.length > 0) {
    alert(matches[1]);
}
```

Move the grouping parenthesis right 1 character if you also want the space after the first ID.  This assumes that the IDs won't contain a #.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex,

```
(.*)#.*?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sK2hW9)

JS code,

```
> var sText ='DefId #AnyId #MyId';
undefined
> sText = sText.replace(/(.*)#.*?$/g, '$1');
'DefId #AnyId '
```

If you don't want any space after `#AnyId`, then run the below regex to remove that space.

```
> sText = sText.replace(/(.*) #.*?$/g, '$1');
'DefId #AnyId'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get rig of everything after last `#` in the string, use:

```
sText.replace(/#[^#]+$/, '');
```